# Printing the endpoint of the current Docker context

Tags: docker, go-templates, docker-cli

I am using Docker CLI.
I want to print the current Docker endpoint according to the current Docker context.

Here is the output structure:

```bash
$ docker context ls --format '{{ json . }}' | jq
{
  "Current": true,
  "Description": "Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration",
  "DockerEndpoint": "unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock",
  "KubernetesEndpoint": "",
  "Name": "default",
  "StackOrchestrator": "swarm"
}
{
  "Current": false,
  "Description": "Rootless mode",
  "DockerEndpoint": "unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock",
  "KubernetesEndpoint": "",
  "Name": "rootless",
  "StackOrchestrator": ""
}
```

The closest solution I have is:

```bash
$ docker context ls --format '{{- if .Current -}} {{- .DockerEndpoint -}} {{- end -}}'
unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock
```

Can I get rid of the output blank lines via a **pure go template mere enhancement**?

**I don't want to rely on any additional shell command to keep it portable across all environments**